# heroku not displaying updates in chrome, but is in safari

Tags: github, heroku

I have been working on a simple portfolio for myself and have it deployed to an app on heroku.  I have used the typical commands to add, commit, and push to GitHub and everything is updating normally there.

My issue is that when I open the app from Heroku in Chrome, it is not displaying the recent updates.  When I open the link on my phone, it looks correct according to my HTML and CSS code.  I have tried both automatic and manual deploy methods, but I still cannot get Chrome to display any of my updates.

Has anybody experienced this? I'm including screenshots below.

[How it displays in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjE79.png)

[How it displays in Mobile Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jcFM.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome sometime uses previously cache data of website to load website faster unlike safari, try using incognito mode or another pc or even a smartphone. There is also a service called browserling where you can test out on different browsers.

Comment: That must be what it was.  I went into Edge and it pulled up normally.  I never would have thought of the cache, but I will now.  Thanks for the tip on browserling, that's a great resource.  Thank you!